# LiveData in RecyclerView does not update when ExpandableListView child item is clicked

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-activity, android-room, android-livedata

**Expected result:** When clicking on an item in the navigation drawer, the tab menu shows a list of tasks whose `workId` is `selectedWordId`.

**Actual result:** The list of tasks does not update after clicking on another item. I have to click on tab 3 and then tab 1 again.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WorkListAdapter.OnDetailDeleteClickListener {

    private WorkListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    private TabPagerAdapter adapter;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private final List<CustomMenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<CustomMenuItem> menuItemsTodo = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<CustomMenuItem> menuItemsDoing = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<CustomMenuItem> menuItemsDone = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<CustomMenuItem> emptyMenuItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<CustomMenuGroupList> menuGroupLists = new ArrayList<>();
    private int selectedWorkId = 0;
    private TaskFragment fragment1 = new TaskFragment(1);
    private TaskFragment fragment2 = new TaskFragment(2);
    private TaskFragment fragment3 = new TaskFragment(3);
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private String username;
    private WorkItemDAO workItemDAO;
    private TaskDAO taskDAO;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        username = intent.getStringExtra("username");

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        workItemDAO = AndroidNCDatabase.getDatabase(this).workItemDAO();
        taskDAO = AndroidNCDatabase.getDatabase(this).taskDAO();

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        adapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(fragment1, "Cần làm", "tab1");
        adapter.addFragment(fragment2, "Đang thực hiện", "tab2");
        adapter.addFragment(fragment3, "Hoàn thành", "tab3");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        binding.etSearch.setOnClickListener(v -> binding.etSearch.setCursorVisible(true));

        expandableListAdapter = new WorkListAdapter(this, menuGroupLists, menuItems);
        expandableListAdapter.setOnDetailDeleteClickListener(this);
        binding.drawerListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        binding.drawerListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(this::onNoChildGroup);
        binding.drawerListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(this::onNoChildGroup);
        binding.drawerListView.setOnChildClickListener((parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id) -> {
            selectedWorkId = expandableListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).getWorkId();
            expandableListAdapter.setSelectedChildPosition(childPosition);
            fragment1.setSelectedWorkId(selectedWorkId);
            fragment2.setSelectedWorkId(selectedWorkId);
            fragment3.setSelectedWorkId(selectedWorkId);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        });

        ImageView iconMenu = findViewById(R.id.iconMenu);

        iconMenu.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (binding.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                binding.drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });


    }

    public void onNoChildGroup(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginIntent);
            finish();
        } else if (position == 1) {
            openAddWorkDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskFragment.java**

```
    public class TaskFragment extends Fragment{
    
    
        public interface OnDeleteTaskListener {
            void onDeleteTask(Task task);
        }
    
        private OnDeleteTaskListener deleteTaskListener;
    
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private int statusId;
        private int selectedWorkId;
        private List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        private TaskListAdapter adapter;
        TaskViewModel taskViewModel;
    
        public TaskFragment(int statusId) {
            this.statusId = statusId;
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, container, false);
            recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(50));
            adapter = new TaskListAdapter(getActivity(), taskList);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            taskViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(TaskViewModel.class);
                taskViewModel.getTaskByWorkId(selectedWorkId).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), tasks -> {
                    taskList.clear();
                    for (Task t : tasks) {
                        if (t.getStatus_id() == this.statusId && t.getWork_id() == selectedWorkId)
                            taskList.add(t);
                    }
                    adapter.setTaskList(taskList);
                });
            return rootView;
        }
        public void setSelectedWorkId(int selectedWorkId) {
            this.selectedWorkId = selectedWorkId;
        }
    }
```

**TaskViewModel.java**

```
public class TaskViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private TaskDAO taskDAO;

    public TaskViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        taskDAO = AndroidNCDatabase.getDatabase(application).taskDAO();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Task>> getTaskByWorkId(int workId) {
        return taskDAO.getTaskByWorkId(workId);
    }
}
```